# youtube-dl set playlist quality

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, youtube, youtube-dl

Running on Windows, latest version of youtube-dl.exe

I would like to download a playlist at the best possible quality (1080)

My issue is that -f command has varied results depending on what I use:

[testing with a single file instead of the playlist returns the following]

Whenever I run `-f bestvideo+bestaudio` I get two files (but the video file is in 1080p)

Whenever I run `-f best` I get (one file both audio and video but at 720p)

Found other commands but they seem to be specifically for ubuntu

I've gotten familiar with `-cit` commands and many others, but am really stuck on this one.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does it throw an error about ffprobe/avprobe?